# ssh key authentication not working from network/if-up.d/ scripts

Tags: shell, ssh, su, key-authentication

I have two nearly identical scripts in `network/if-up` that need to access SSH keys. Permissions on SSH private keys are 600, so how can my scripts access these keys?

I would prefer to keep the SSH keys associated with a user account I set up for the task that these scripts perform.

I don't know how to find the user that runs the scripts in `network/if-up` and I also have not had any luck trying to use `su -l -c "my_command" mytaskuser` in my scripts. Hopefully I'm just making a simple mistake.

On Ubuntu my scripts are located in `/etc/network/if-up.d` and in other distros (e.g., openSuse) they are in `etc/sysconfig/network/if-up.d`.

Both my scripts look similar to this (I'll just use one example to keep the question focused):

```
#!/bin/sh
LOGDATE="_`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H%M`"
scp -i /home/mytaskuser/.ssh/id_rsa /home/mytaskuser/some.log  mytaskuser@example.com:somelog${LOGDATE}.log
exit 0
```

The script works totally correctly if I log in as mytaskuser and run it manually. It fails without any obvious error messages when run automatically from `if-up.d/`.

I have tried variations like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
LOGDATE="_`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H%M`"
su -l -c "scp -i /home/mytaskuser/.ssh/id_rsa /home/mytaskuser/some.log  mytaskuser@example.com:somelog${LOGDATE}.log" mytaskuser
exit 0
```

That hasn't worked. The only way the script works is when I run it while logged in as the user that owns the SSH key (id_rsa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `scp` as root, then it looks for files in root's home directory, including the `known_hosts` file. If the server's public key is not in `~/.ssh/known_hosts`, then ssh prompts the user to ask whether to add the key. If there is no terminal to prompt the user, ssh refuses to connect since it cannot ensure that the host is the right one.

You should run `scp` as your own user (`mytaskuser`).

```
su -c "scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa ~/some.log  mytaskuser@example.com:somelog${LOGDATE}.log" mytaskuser
```

Don't pass the `-l` option to `su`: that runs a login shell, which ignores the command passed with `-c`.

Comment: Thank you. One thing I stumbled across while testing is to use the setuid bit. I removed `su -c` and set the owner of the script to `mytaskuser` and set permissions to `6755` and it appears to have worked. (I say appears because I have had a few false successes so far in my testing.) Which approach will be more reliable and robust? `setuid` or `su -c "command" mytaskuser`?

Comment: @MountainX Setuid is ignored for scripts! Maybe you've entered the key in `/root/.ssh/known_hosts`? Or you were running the script as yourself and the key was in `/home/mountainx/.ssh/known_hosts`?

Comment: None of the above. I'm confused as to how it is working, but it is working...